# How to add element key & value to object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I am trying to add key value from array to person object, i mocked below code similar approach it is coming undefined object when we assign key/value pair to object. What would be right approach to achieve this task ?

main.js

```
const person = {
    Name: "John klmeni"
    age: 29 
} 

const address = [{address: '111 main st"}] 
for (let obj in person) {
    address.forEach(element ,==> {
        obj[key] = element.key
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: person.address = '111 main st';

Comment: Am I missing something?

Comment: There are numerous issues in this code. What is the expected output?

Comment: expected output should be person object with address property with key and value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to do the following?

```js
const person = {
  Name: "John klmeni",
  age: 29 
} 

const address = [{address: '111 main st'}];
const newPerson = address.reduce(
  (result,item)=>
    Object.assign({},result,item),
  person
);
console.log(newPerson);
```